# zsh config & automatic function loading

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I created a folder inside my `.config/zsh` called `.zsh_functions` while building alacritty from source to add alacritty functions inside of it which worked as expected.

I'm like cool, by adding `fpath+=${ZDOTDIR:-~}/.zsh_functions` to my `.zshrc` I can throw a file which contains a function and zsh will pick it up and I don't have to create an alias for it.

Also I will note here that I do have zdotdir set inside my `.zshenv` which is located in my home dir with:

```
ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.config/zsh
```

I created a file called `my_functions` with a simple function:

```
myserver() {
    typeset username="username"
    typeset host="128.0.0.1" #changed the IP for illustration purpose

    ssh "$username@$host"
}
```

Now, although the alacritty functions works, my function doesn't unless I for loop my `.zsh_functions` folder

```
for file in "${ZDOTDIR:-~}"/.zsh_functions/*(.); do
    source "$file"
done
```

I tried adding this instead of a for loop:

```
# Add .zsh_functions to path
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
fpath+=${ZDOTDIR:-~}/.zsh_functions
```

When I echo $FPATH I see that `.zsh_functions` folder is being included into $FPATH, but yet the function is not recognized. Even when I type `typeset -f myserver` I get nothing.

So I wrote all that to ask you this, do I got to explicitly source all files within my `.zsh_functions` , or should including it to the $FPATH enough?

Some plugins and functions in zsh is very sensitive where

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

is placed inside `.zshrc`

I also tried:

```
chmod +x my_functions
```

Nothing seems to work until I do the for loop which seems to be redundant since I'm adding it to the fpath.

Any clarification would help, thanks in advance!

Comment: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Autoloading-Functions explains how it works, what you have to do, and how files should be named.

Comment: AFIK, it does not help to set ZDOTDIR in .zshenv. This file is also locate at $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv, and the cat would bite into its tail. From what I know, zsh decides, where its dot files are searched, **before** any one of them has been processed. Hence, `ZDOTDIR=~/mydot zsh` would work, but setting ZDOTDIR inside one of the startup files wouldn't.